# Django rest api: How to handle method object has no attribute 'COOKIES' error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a `django` api. I want to enforce it to have `csrf` cookie using `@ensure_csrf_cookie` but I get error using this `curl` command:

```
curl -i -c -H 'Accept: application/json; indent=4'  -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -H 'Referer:https://dev.ga.coach' -X POST  https://mydomain/users/:register/ -d "id=222111&firstname=zinonas&yearofbirth=2007&lastname=Antoniou&othernames="
```

The error is:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  141.                     result = middleware.process_request(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/middleware/csrf.py" in process_request
  205.         csrf_token = self._get_token(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/middleware/csrf.py" in _get_token
  177.                 cookie_token = request.COOKIES[settings.CSRF_COOKIE_NAME]

Exception Type: AttributeError at /users/:register/
Exception Value: 'ApiUserRegister' object has no attribute 'COOKIES'
```

My class in `views.py` is:

```
class ApiUserRegister(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (BasicAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = ()
    serializer_class = RegisterUserSerializer

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    @ensure_csrf_cookie
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = RegisterUserSerializer(data=request.data)
        # Check format and unique constraint
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        data = serializer.data

        token = get_token(request)
        if User.objects.filter(id=data['id']).exists():
            user = User.objects.get(id=data['id'])
            is_new = "false"
            resp_status = status.HTTP_200_OK
        else:
            user = User.objects.create(id=data['id'],
                                       firstname=data['firstname'],
                                       yearofbirth=data['yearofbirth'],
                                       lastname=data['lastname'],
                                       othernames=data['othernames'])
            user.save()
            is_new = "true"
            resp_status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED
        resp = {"user": serializer.get_serialized(user),
                "isnew": is_new,
                "csrftoken": token}
        return Response( resp, status=resp_status, headers = {"X-CSRFToken":token, "Referer":"https://mydomain/users/:register/"})
```

In settings.py I have:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        #'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        #'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        #'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    )
}
```

Comment: You need to use `method_decorator` on *both* decorators. Although why you want both `csrf_exempt` and `ensure_csrf_cookie` is not clear.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I only want `ensure_csrf_cookie` but I also get the same error if I use it only this.

Comment: As I said, you need to use it with `method_decorator`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman In case I use `method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie)` I can't get `csrftoken` cookie in `postman`.